# How does Page Cache work in memory? Specifically in Linux

Tags: caching, process, kernel

As we know, operating system implement a page mechanism to achieve fast access. Every time, when a process requests the kernel to load binary from disk to its memory space, kernel will first have look at the page cache. If binaries are already cached in the page cache, then there is no need to access the hardware disk. In this way, OS can reduce the overhead.

However, I have question.

As we know, OS will help page cache to allocate pages in physical memory to hold data that will be potentially used soon. When process's requesting data are discovered in page cache by the kernel, what will the kernel pass to the process? Will the kernel copy the content of the PageCache's page holding the data in need to a new page that is allocated to this process? Or the kernel just return the pointer of the page in the PageCache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many operating systems out there, so if we're talking about any arbitrary real, future or theoretical operating system the answer could be "either".

However, for all real operating systems that I'm aware of, the page will only be in memory once.  It would be very inefficient to create a copy of each page, and doing so would not create any benefit.

Comment: What if We are talking about Linux? We know that the struct address_space will be used by the OS to describe a page cache for a file. How does Linux deal with this?

Comment: The file contents are loaded just once and shared.  See http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/